# Yiic migrate error due to pdo_mysql driver not found

Tags: php, mysql, yii, pdo

I'm trying to learn Yii, but I'm stuck with a very persistent error that rises whenever I use yiic.
First system details: Ubuntu 13.04 with apache2, php 5.5.3 and mysql 5.5.3.
I run`/yiic migrate`

inside  /protected of the webapp I'm developing.

I get the error:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver' in /var/www/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:382
```

Which seems to be because at line 382 of CDbConnection.php, the script checks if pod_mysql is installed, but can't find it.

```
`if($this->_pdo===null)
 {
    if(empty($this->connectionString))
         throw new CDbException('CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.');
    try
    {
         Yii::trace('Opening DB connection','system.db.CDbConnection');
         $this->_pdo=$this->createPdoInstance();
         $this->initConnection($this->_pdo);
         $this->_active=true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        if(YII_DEBUG)
        {
           throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection:'.

                                  $e->getMessage(),(int)$e->getCode(),$e->errorInfo);

        }
        else
        {                                        
           Yii::log($e->getMessage(),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'exception.CDbException');

           throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.' 

                                  ,(int)$e->getCode(),$e->errorInfo);
    }
    }
}
```

^^ Here is the relevant snippet of code.

The result of running

```
php -i|grep PDO gives 
PDO
PDO support => enabled 
PDO drivers => sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

So my problem seems to be that only the sqlite driver is running.  However, I've ensured to check that php-mysql is installed (as pdo_mysql is deprecated and is inside this package).  I've ran out of ideas on what to do, and will appreciate any and all help!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Console applications have their own config stored in `protected/config/console.php`. Please make sure you've got a database component configured there.

Comment: I have set up db component of the console.php in config the same way I have set it up in main.php, and I can verify that the webapp can create, read, and update the database.  Except can't use yiic migrate...

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 on a virtual box

Comment: Here's what I think is happening: Ubuntu has a separate config for php on the console. That one might not include `pdo_mysql`. Run `php --ini` to confirm this.

Comment: php --ini shows that there is only one config file. In the said file I can't find any .os extensions (I think pdo_mysql.so doesn't exist separately anymore anyways). I'm not sure if I've understood you precisely. Should there be 2 php.ini files?

Comment: `php --ini` shouldn't list *any* files with .so extension. It should only show you which .ini files are loaded. It's been more than a year since I last touched Ubuntu, but I'm pretty sure the PHP CLI had its own config. `php --ini` should reflect that.

Comment: So I have found 3 php.ini files with 'find / -name php.ini' respectively in '/etc/php/cli/php.ini', '/etc/php/apache2/php.ini', and '/usr/local/lib/php.ini '.  they all have the same PDO and pdo_mysql set up: [Pdo]
'
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict
;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name
[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
pdo_mysql.default_socket=' Is there any changes I need to do here? Thanks!

Comment: Lines starting with `;` are commented out. So if the pdo_mysql.so isn't loaded, that's where I'd take a look at. If that doesn't help, I've been tremendously wrong. Try on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from your *phpcli.ini* instead of *php.ini.* in your *phpcli.ini* you should add :

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

as in *php.ini*